# Creating an Action in QGIS with multiple Expression?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-2

I want to create an action in QGIS with multiple Expression. But unable to do so. I want to open images from two different directories with one action. Is it possible? How can I do so?

e.g.

```
Type : open
name : open Photo
D:\image\Path_1\[%"Photo"%].jpg
D:\image\Path_2\[%"Photo"%].jpg
```

But it's not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it work when you specify one .jpg **only** ?

Comment: + Where do u want the pictures to be opened ? In QGIS ? In a web Browser ? in the Windows Explorer ?

Comment: Yes it work when i specify picture format(e.g .jpg).Because i use just picture name in column.
I want to open picture in window explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Still awaiting some clarification but here is a working example i just tried (QGIS 3.4.4) :

Action - type Python

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView

myWV1 = QWebView(None)
myWV1.load(QUrl('file:///D://tempo//' + [% concat('\'',"FIRST_FIELD",'\'') %] + '-1.png'))
print('après')
myWV1.show()

myWV2 = QWebView(None)
myWV2.load(QUrl('file:///D://tempo//' + [% concat('\'',"SECOND_FIELD",'\'') %] + '-2.png'))
myWV2.show()
```

Which is opening 2 images (in 'local' files) in two separate (non modal) windows. Some tweaking certainly required if you need another behaviour ...

I played a bit with strings to show you a working syntax (*escaping quotes ...*)

Comment: I have one field in which all picture name are stored in Qgis points layer. I want to open picture in window explorer with the help of qgis action and i create a action which is working perfectly but i have issue in that because this action is working when all picture are stored in one folder. I just want to open image in window explorer from two different folder in one action. Please help me out.